# What are the exact buffs defeating Rayquaza gives in Pokemon Unite?

Tags: pokemon-unite

Rayquaza is still relatively new in Pokemon unite as the "final" boss, but I am still unsure all of the buffs that you get from defeating it. It seems like this may be common since not all go to immediately score vs fighting after defeating Rayquaza.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official website](https://unite.pokemon.com/en-us/news/pokemon-unite-anniversary-update-brings-new-map-fresh-pokemon-and-more/)

> The team that defeats Rayquaza will receive a temporary shield that, while active, increases attack power and goal-scoring speed and makes scoring attempts unblockable.

Note that damages that bypass shields will stop you from scoring.